# Overloading operators * and ->

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I tried to overload the dereference operators (`*`) and (`->`) for a simple class.

```
class Base
{
private:
    int i;
    int j;

public:
    Base(int i): i(i), j(i), k(90) { }

    void print() 
    { 
        cout << i << j << endl; 
    }

    Base &operator*(void)
    {
        cout << "inside * operator" << endl;

        return *this;

    }

    Base *operator->(void)
    {
        cout << "inside -> operator" << endl;

        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Base(100);

    int j = b->k;

    int l = (*b).k;

    cout << j << l<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here the overloaded operator `->` does not get called. But when I use `int j = (*b)->k`, then the overloaded operator `->` gets called.

I did not understand this why it is so? and also i didn't able to call overloaded `operator*` at all. I understand that we overload such operators mainly for smart pointers but i didnt get the reason here. any help???

Answer (score 3):

`b` is a pointer. The `->` and `*` operators you are applying to `b` de-reference the pointer, not the thing it points to. Furthermore, the language does not allow you to overload those operators for pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

The overloaded `*` and `->` operators are only used if the left-hand side of the operator is an object of type `Base`, but in the example you have above, the left-hand side of the operator is a pointer of type `Base*`. To invoke `operator*` or `operator ->`, you'll need to use actual, concrete `Base` objects. For example:

```
Base b{100};
*b = ...
b->...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1: I'm ashamed to say that I personally had to use `Qt` before I even bothered learning why this is so.